# Rigging Character with complex outfits

Tags: rigging, armature, parent

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4IEk.png

I want to make the rig control the fingers and the Finger Armor but I get the "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones" Error. It seems like blender is having an issue with assigning object vertices to the bones. Merging the object together did no fix the problem. I'm having this problem all across my character, but for some reason there are no resources on rigging character with a complex outfits.

Another question is
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pxni.png
what's the best way of rigging solid armor pieces, do I want to use automatic weights or is there a better way like parenting the object to the bone so that the solid armor piece doesn't bend.

Also if anyone has links to resources on rigging characters with complex outfits please post.

Comment: So I found that when removing the metal bolts on the metal finger armor makes it work, but this doesn't make me understand any more why I'm having this issue

Comment: it may have to do with inverted normals, or a too dense mesh. For the rigging of this kind of mesh (robot, armor, engine, etc), don't parent With Automatic Weights, parent With Empty Groups, then assign each part to the group it is supposed to be part of